# LinkedIn API "Empty oauth2 access token" error

Tags: python, linkedin-api

Sorry if this is question is not suitable for stackoverflow.

I've got access token from Linkedin API. I am trying to use it however I am not sure how to include my access_token. I cannot find any example on documentation.

```
base_url = f'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/people?access_token={linkedin_key}&format=json'
requests.get(base_url).json()
```

This outputs

```
    {'serviceErrorCode': 65604,
 'message': 'Empty oauth2 access token',
 'status': 401}
```

does anyone know what's wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

The access token param you need to pass is `oauth2_access_token` not `access_token`.

For example:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?oauth2_access_token={linkedin_key}
```

I can't find it in the docs and it's been a while, but that's how I use it in my app.

Comment: Thank you for your help! do you know how to look at all of job posting of specific job? ex: I want to look at all job postings of the role, data scientist.

Comment: That I don't know. You will have to look at their docs. I'm also afraid the jobs API may be restricted to their marketing partners.

Comment: any solution till yet because i am also suffering from this issue ?

Comment: Had similar problems with out of date online references and the usual vague and ambiguous API docs. This works.

Comment: @ErvinKalemi from where you will get access_token?

Answer (score 4):

I think they want you to pass it in the headers based on my reading of their docs

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow?context=linkedin/context#step-4-make-authenticated-requests

```
requests.get(base_url,headers={"Authorization":"Bearer {access_token}"}).json()
```

Comment: it tells me that I need to add format at the end. in such case do I add it at base_url? which will become                                                 base_url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/people?~format=json'

Comment: FWIW, when passing the same valid token via HEADER and GET at the same time I get `{'serviceErrorCode': 65603, 'message': 'Multiple access token provided', 'status': 401}` hinting at both types of auth being seen, at a bare minimum.

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't try to include it directly in header. Instead go to the Authorization tab, select OAuth2.0 and give access token there. Refer to the image[image]